# Eclipse-project to makefile for ant/maven/gradle/

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

Today I faced problems in starting eclipse (reinstall etc. did not work). I had to use a vanilla eclipse and with luck it was working.

With that I experienced the problem of an IDE that is not working. That can be a mess if you need a quick bugfix for a hot system.

Is there a tool that takes an eclipse-project and converts it into a makefile for a more basic tool (like ant, maven, gradle, ...) that work from the commandline?

Sure I can make it by hand but because it should be only a safety I would prefere the automatic way and keep the development-work in the IDE.

**EDIT**:
Or maybe: Is there an build-command that works on the commandline without starting the IDE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Running "gradle init" from the command line will attempt to create a build.gradle for your project. If your project layout is "conventional" it might do a good job. If it finds anomalies it tends to give up.  Constructing a simple Gradle build script for a simple project takes a few minutes once you get used to it.  Searching the web with intelligent queries will tend to find lots of examples.

Adding the "Gradle Nature" in Eclipse is simple if the project is buildable from the command line with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use m2e eclipse plugin to convert your existing projects to maven projects. But you have to do it before hand(while your eclipse is still working)

https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/

Comment: That is a conversion. It will make my eclipse-project to a maven-build. Is there a tool that does not change my project but also generates a makefile - maybe also without eclipse.

Comment: @chris01 the configuration is adding `<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>` and  maven buildCommand to the .project file. You can comment out these lines and use it as pure java project.(Not a automatic way though) But using maven has many advantages, If you can integrate in your development.